# how can I share an Image using Facebook Graph API like share button

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

I want to open share pop up window of facebook when user clicks on a particular link (Not the share button). I want to do this in php and want to share an image.

Note: I want to provide the source of the image which comes dynamically.

Can any one help me please?

Please ask for more information if you want.

Thank you.

**Update:**

Below is my code:

The main page where the link is:

```
<li id="FB_post" style="display:none;"><a id="post_image_href"  href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
```

In the js (Click event)

```
$("#post_image_href").click(function(e) {
        if($('.prodct_personalize_but a').html() != 'Cancel' && $('#zoom1').length>0 ){         
            $(this).attr('href','https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+$('#zoom1').attr('href'));
        }       
        else if ($(".image-main-container").css('display') != 'none')
        {
            if ($('.product_box23').css('display') != 'none')
            {

                e.preventDefault();
                setProperDynamicTextPosition();
                var data = $('#personalise_form').serialize();

                $('#loader_img').show();
                $.post(ajaxurl, data + '&action=save_personalise_image', function(response) {
                    if (response != '' && response != undefined) {
                        var Aryresponse = response.split('###');
                        $("#post_image_href").attr('href','https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + Aryresponse[0]);
                        document.location.href = $("#post_image_href").attr('href');
                        $('#loader_img').hide();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Link which is created when I click on the Facebook link and go to facebook page:

In share dilog box: the current url of the browser and in the address bar: the updated link.
For Ex.  https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://www.picpixa.com/wp-content/plugins/create-own-object/test-img/final_ProductImage_1405751994-2197.png

Please let me know if you want more information.

**Update In JS Function:**

I have made change in my js (click event function):

Below is the updated function:

```
$("#post_image_href").click(function(e) {
        var url='';
        if($('.prodct_personalize_but a').html() != 'Cancel' && $('#zoom1').length>0 ){         
            //$(this).attr('href','https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+$('#zoom1').attr('href'));
            url = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+$('#zoom1').attr('href');
            console.log("If: "+ $('#zoom1').attr('href'));
            console.log("URL: "+ url);
        }       
        else if ($(".image-main-container").css('display') != 'none')
        {
            if ($('.product_box23').css('display') != 'none')
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                setProperDynamicTextPosition();
                var data = $('#personalise_form').serialize();

                $('#loader_img').show();
                $.post(ajaxurl, data + '&action=save_personalise_image', function(response) {
                    if (response != '' && response != undefined) {
                        var Aryresponse = response.split('###');
                        //$("#post_image_href").attr('href','https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + Aryresponse[0]);
                       url = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + Aryresponse[0];
                       console.log("Else: "+ Aryresponse[0]);
                       console.log("URL: "+ url);
                       window.open(url, "popupWindow", "width=450,height=400,scrollbars=no"); //If I don't use this the pop up don't open.
                       //In fact this is og no use as this is not opening but still I have to put this here to run below winodw.open.
                        $('#loader_img').hide();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        console.log("The URL is: "+url);
        window.open(url, "popupWindow", "width=450,height=400,scrollbars=no");
    });
```

**Another Update: Imp. Info:**

I thought that this might me the issue of the Meta Tags. And it is. I am giving all the required meta tags in the main page but when I did the debug of the url I am passing it is giving me the below result.

[Click here to see the result](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.picpixa.com%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Fcreate-own-object%2Ftest-img%2Ffinal_ProductImage_1406129710-12370.png)

Can anyone find me a solution?

Comment: Please post the specific code you are having problems with.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[image_url]

Comment: @faost you just gave me what I wanted...
I just have minor problem that when I share the image, after sharing in the facebook It does not showing the thumbnail. It is showing page not found. But when I click on that link it shows correct image. Can you please suggest any solution on this?
And please add your comment as answer so that I can accept it.
And need one more help.
Instead of opening a new window I want to open a pop up.
Can you  give me the code for that?

Comment: @faost I am facing a new problem now.
it is not taking the image_url which I am giving.
It is taking the url from the address bar by it self.
Note that The url I am gining is coming dynamically.
I may post my code if you want...

Comment: @faost Please see my code in the question in Update section...

Comment: @faost can you please find out the solution?

Comment: @AndrewArnold I have post the code I am using...
Please help me to solve the problem...

Comment: I found the problem.

Facebook tries to find the tags in the url I am passing. As I am passing the URL of the image, it surely will not able to find the meta tag in the url I am passing using sharer.php?u=[imgUrl].

The image is being shared but on the timeline Image is not being displayed and title is "Page Not Found - Pic Pixa" But on the timeline when I click on the link I am getting the perfect Image.

Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: Hello faost,
I am facing a problem while importing photos from user timeline.
If user have uploaded multiple images, then those images are not being imported in my website. Otherwise all is working as expected.